# deny local logon for a new user through command line windows server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, command-line-interface, user-management

I am creating a local user account that I want to be able to connect over ftp, but not log on to the server, I believe the way to do this is to deny local logon but am unsure how to achieve this via the command line.  This needs to run from an installer on windows server 2008 hence the command line requirement.

I believe it involves somehow applying SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight to the user but the only way I can find to do this is using ntrights.exe which is not shipped with ws2008.

Is it possible to do this via the command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't allow them RDP (by default they won't have it unless they are in the admins group)...they shouldn't have physical access regardless.  Other than that, all I know of is using `NTrights.exe` which you pointed out...and didn't ship with Windows regardless, but was a resource kit tool.  You can still get it and use it, but I get that you want to do it with built-in commands during the installer.

Why not simply change the local security policy on the server to only allow Administrators and Backup Operators the right to `Allow Logon Locally`?  That would suffice just fine I would think.

Answer (score 3):

TheCleaner is correct, no registry value for these User Rights Assignments.

Use the NTRights.exe from the command line.

```
NTRights.exe -u username +r SeDenyInteractiveLogonRight
```

Reference article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/315276

Answer (score -1):

[The answer in this thread isn't exact, however it should start you on your way.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11751137/how-do-i-deny-log-on-through-terminal-services-rdp-from-a-command-line)

In a nutshell, you just want to use the command line to modify the registry value of the Deny Logon Locally (or Interactive Remote or both).

Comment: There's no such registry value.